# Updating x-axis labels in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Here is a toy piece of code that illustrates my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], '-o', animated=True)


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,


def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    ax.set_xlim(np.amin(xdata), np.amax(xdata))
    return ln,


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

If I set `blit=True` then the data points are plotted just how I want them. However, the x-axis labels/ticks remain static.

If I set `blit=False` then the x-axis labels and ticks update just how I want them. However, none of the data points are ever plotted.

How can I get *both the plotted data (sine curve) **and** the x-asis data to update"?*

Comment: Use `animated=False` and `blit=False`. I might write up a complete answer with explanation of why that is later.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest WOT?! okay, I would really appreciate an in depth explanation here. I am baffled. BTW, love your name! Great play… ☺

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First concerning blitting: Blitting is only applied to the content of the axes. It will affect the inner part of the axes, but not the outer axes decorators. Hence if using `blit=True` the axes decorators are not updated. Or inversely put, if you want the scale to update, you need to use `blit=False`.

Now, in the case from the question this leads to the line not being drawn. The reason is that the line has its `animated` attribute set to `True`. However, "animated" artists are not drawn by default. This property is actually meant to be used for blitting; but if no blitting is performed it will result in the artist neither be drawn nor blitted. It might have been a good idea to call this property `blit_include` or something similar to avoid confusion from its name.
Unfortunately, it looks like it's also not well documented. You find however a comment in the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/90037f413a44def934e6b172ee6163b64c007722/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L235) saying

> ```
> # if the artist is animated it does not take normal part in the
> # draw stack and is not expected to be drawn as part of the normal
> # draw loop (when not saving) so do not propagate this change
> ```

So in total, one can ignore the presence of this argument, unless you use blitting. Even when using blitting, it can be ignored in *most cases*, because that property is set internally anyways.

To conclude the solution here is to not use `animated` and to not use `blit`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], '-o')


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)


def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    ax.set_xlim(np.amin(xdata), np.amax(xdata))


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @Eric Because I forgot to do so. Thank you for reminding me.